# Pivot on column with multiple values for a group without aggregation, with all Combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to pivot below table grouping on ID and Role, with all the combination redn values. Below is how my input looks and expected output

Input:

```
ID  Role    redn    Value
1   Role1   redn1   V1
1   Role1   redn1   V2
1   Role1   redn2   V3
1   Role2   redn1   V1
1   Role2   redn2   V2
```

Output:

```
ID  Role    redn1   redn2
1   Role1   V1     V3
1   Role1   V2     V3
1   Role2   V1     V2
```

How can i do this? in my actual data i have 8 different redn ( redn1 to redn8) with each redn can have one or many values (V1.. V100).

Comment: Your output is rather confusing. Why is V3 on both rows? Or is this that you want every combination of redn1 and redn2 for each Role?

Comment: Yes!, I need every combination of redn1 and redn2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to [apply doc samples](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)?

```
SELECT ID, Role, [redn1], [redn2], [redn3], ..., [redn8]
FROM
(SELECT ID,  Role,    redn,    Value
    FROM [Input]) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
MAX([Output])
FOR redn IN ([redn1], [redn2], [redn3], ..., [redn8])
) AS PivotTable;
```

**Edited due OP comment**

```
select ID,  Role, s1.value as redn1,    s2.value as redn2
from source s1 
inner join source s2
on s1.ID=s2.ID and s1.Role=s2.Role and s1.redn != s2.redn
```

Comment: Thanks, this will not work and will return only 2 rows for the example i have specified, But i need all the possible combinations of redn1 redn2..redn8 values per role

Comment: Thanks a lot!, this would help me. I hope u mean S1.Value as Redn1 ,S2.Value as Redn2 in the query you provided. This gives me expected result along with few extra records, i can try eliminating them.

Comment: fixed. You have several questions with high answer upvotes without  check as 'answer'. You know how to do it. Just review in order to keep hight your  ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've been doing it wrong but I often use IF statements or Case statements to pivot my data in SQL.

For your example I'd use something like:

```
SELECT Id, Role,
       SUM(IF(redn = 'redn1', Value, 0)) AS redn1,
       SUM(IF(redn = 'redn2', Value, 0)) AS redn2
FROM dataset
GROUP BY Id, Role
```

Obviously this wouldn't work if you're expecting like 100 different columns from the pivot. Also if Value isn't numeric you would want to use something other than SUM and probably a null value instead of 0.

Is that what you were looking for?

Oh and here's [a short tutorial on pivoting in SQL](https://community.modeanalytics.com/sql/tutorial/sql-pivot-table/) from Mode.

Comment: Value is not numeric, If i use max then i will get only one row per role. I am looking for all combination, in example i mentioned ,there are 2 different value for  redn1 i.e. v1 and v2. and one value for redn2 i.e. v3. So in the result i need both combination   redn1 v1 with redn2 v3 and redn1 v2 with redn2 V3

Comment: May be am confusing you guys, let me see if i can describe it better!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this with some way, but am not sure if this is best way to do it. Posting my answer as it might help some people.

```
/* Source Data */ 
--DROP TABLE #Temp
SELECT 1 AS ID, 'Role1' AS Role,'redn1' redn, 'V1' [Value]
INTO #Temp
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 AS ID, 'Role1' AS Role,'redn1' redn, 'V2' [Value]
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 AS ID, 'Role1' AS Role,'redn2' redn, 'V3' [Value]
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 AS ID, 'Role2' AS Role,'redn1' redn, 'V1' [Value]
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 AS ID, 'Role2' AS Role,'redn2' redn, 'V2' [Value]

/*Query*/
WITH Source_Dataset
AS
(
    Select   ID
            ,Role
            ,RednNo = CASE WHEN redn = 'redn1' then 1 
                           WHEN redn =  'redn2'  then 2 
                      END
            ,[Value]
    FROM #Temp
)
select DISTINCT S1.ID
      ,S1.Role
      ,s1.value  redn1
      ,s2.value  redn2
from Source_Dataset s1 
inner join Source_Dataset s2
on s1.ID=s2.ID and s1.Role=s2.Role and s1.RednNo < s2.RednNo 
ORDER by 1,2
```

It work fine for me even with 8 different 'redn', But i need to self join 8 times and compare like i did above. Only issue is i should have all 8 different 'redn' for each of the 'Role' and it is true in my case.